# Resize image preserving aspect ratio in Tensorflow

Tags: image, image-processing, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am fairly new to TF. I am trying to resize an image tensor so that the lowest dimension of the image is a constant value LO_DIM.
In a non-tf environment, I'd just do something like this:

```
if img.size[0] < img.size[1]:
    h = int(float(LO_DIM * img.size[1]) / img.size[0])
    img = resize(img, [LO_DIM, h])
else:
    w = int(float(LO_DIM * img.size[0]) / img.size[1])
    img = resize(img, [w, LO_DIM])
```

I know that, to resize I should use `tf.image.resize_images`, but I am not sure how to compute the new `w` and `h` considering that the tensor seems to have `shape=<unknown>`.

Note: each image I'm passing might have different sizes, that's why I need it to be computed dynamically. And I'm using LO_DIM to keep aspect ratio and not distort the image.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

If it helps, the processing goal is to get a random NxN patch from the scaled image, but all I could find is `resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` which doesn't seem to do the initial scaling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was answered by this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14213).

Here's a sample snippet to resize tensor image keeping aspext ratio:

```
def resize_image_keep_aspect(image, lo_dim=LO_DIM):
  # Take width/height
  initial_width = tf.shape(image)[0]
  initial_height = tf.shape(image)[1]

  # Take the greater value, and use it for the ratio
  min_ = tf.minimum(initial_width, initial_height)
  ratio = tf.to_float(min_) / tf.constant(lo_dim, dtype=tf.float32)

  new_width = tf.to_int32(tf.to_float(initial_width) / ratio)
  new_height = tf.to_int32(tf.to_float(initial_height) / ratio)

  return tf.image.resize_images(image, [new_width, new_height])
```

Problem of having a tensor of `shape=<unknown>` is solved by using type speific decoders like `tf.image.decode_jpeg` or `tf.image.decode_png`, as opposed to `tf.image.decode_image`

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow 2.x has a built-in method to achieve the same result.

Default Method Usage:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.image.resize(
    images, size, method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR, preserve_aspect_ratio=False,
    antialias=False, name=None
)
```

Example Usage:

```py
>>> max_10_20 = tf.image.resize(image, [10,20], preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
>>> max_10_20.shape.as_list()
[1, 10, 10, 1]
```

The `preserve_aspect_ratio` flag performs the following operations:

- Determines whether to preserve the aspect ratio.
- If the flag is set, then images will be resized to a size that fits in size while preserving the aspect ratio of the original image.
- Scales up the image if the size is bigger than the current size of the image.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize